# MATLAB Error using fzero

Tags: matlab, function, iteration

```
y = @(Er) i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));
y0 = i* sqrt((w/isik_hizi)^2-(2*pi/lamdac)^2);
yansima = @(Er) ((y0/m0)-(y(Er)/m))/((y0/m0)+(y(Er)/m));
T = @(Er) exp(-y(Er)*l);
fx = @(Er) (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T(Er)^2)-(yansima(Er)^2))/(1-(yansima(Er)^2*T(Er)^2)))
cozum = fzero(@(Er) fx(Er),5.72+7.21*i)
```

s11,s12,s21,s22 and other parameters complex.
Function is `fx`. `fx` have `Er`. `Er` is symbol. First `Er` value `5.72+7.21i` . I am looking for new value close to the first Er. But I have problem;

> Error using fzero (line 307) Function value at starting guess must be
>   finite and real.
>
> Error in s0308 (line 76) cozum = fzero(@(Er) fx(Er),5.72+7.21*i)

Comment: try using `fsolve`

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for documentation of [fzero](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html), tells that you can only use a real number as initial guess input argument, so fzero won't be working for complex numbers as in your case.